# Marshal.SizeOf Giving The Wrong Size

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling, sizeof

The code below is giving the wrong size when using Marshal.SizeOf, but I'm not sure why.

Here is the Struct I'm trying to get the size of:

```
//[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
//[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct BLEGenericMsg
{
    public BLEMessageHdr msg_hdr;
    public byte[] msg_body;

    public BLEGenericMsg(int messageSize)
    {
        msg_hdr = new BLEMessageHdr();
        msg_body = new byte[messageSize];
    }
};
```

Here is the code that populates the struct and calls the serialize function:

```
    BLEGenericMsg hostKeyMsg = new BLEGenericMsg(serializedPublicBytes.Length);
    hostKeyMsg.msg_hdr.msg_id = MESSAGE_BASE_EVENT + EVENT_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY;

    hostKeyMsg.msg_body = serializedPublicBytes;

    //Only get the size of the body for the entire message, not counter or header
    hostKeyMsg.msg_hdr.msg_body_sz = (uint)hostKeyMsg.msg_body.Length;
    BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("public Key Size: " + hostKeyMsg.msg_hdr.msg_body_sz + "\n");

    byte[] temp = Serialize(hostKeyMsg);
    BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("temp Size: " + (uint)temp.Length + "\n");
```

Here is the serialize function that is getting the size of the struct:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T s)
    where T : struct
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("BLEGenericMsg Size: " + size + "\n");
    var array = new byte[size];
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return array;
}
```

The size of serializedPublicBytes is 91 bytes, 
the rest of the struct is 6 bytes. 
So I'm expecting the Marshal.SizeOf to be 97 bytes, 
but instead it is showing only about 14 or 16 bytes.
I tried giving the size of msg_body at instantiation, but that didn't make a difference.
What am I missing?

**edit Here is here is the BLEMessageHdr struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct BLEMessageHdr
{
    public ushort msg_id;
    public uint msg_body_sz;
};
```

Comment: I assume BLEMessageHdr  is a class. Its telling you what the size of a pointer to a msg_hdr + the size of a pointer to an array is.

Comment: @pm100: 14 sounds like "size of `msg_hdr`" (no pointer involved) + "size of pointer to byte array"

Comment: maybe. But the main point is that the sizeof doesnt count the size of the byte array - it cant since the sizeof operates on a type, not on an instance Whereas the serialize operation serializes a specific instance

Comment: What does the unmanaged definition of the struct look like?

Comment: I added the BLEMessageHdr above. That is the only definition of the struct. So, if that code is only telling me the size of the msg_hdr and the size of the pointer. How to I get the true size of all the data?

Comment: Yes, it is 14 bytes.  16 bytes if you don't Pack=1.  The troublemaker is the byte[], it gets marshaled as a pointer.  But you intended to create a variable sized structure, in other words the byte[] should have the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=???)] attribute.  The ??? is the big problem, you want different sizes for different messages.  Technically you can declare a dedicated struct for each type of message, now you know the ???.  But consider doing this differently, use BinaryWriter to produce a plain byte[] instead of a structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Marshal.SizeOf()` method is *not* returning the wrong size. In the structure you define:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct BLEGenericMsg
{
    public BLEMessageHdr msg_hdr;
    public byte[] msg_body;

    public BLEGenericMsg(int messageSize)
    {
        msg_hdr = new BLEMessageHdr();
        msg_body = new byte[messageSize];
    }
};
```

the `msg_body` member is known as a "Flexible Array Member" (FAM) in C. It is an illegal construct in C++. Because it is illegal in C++, and because of the inherent uncertainties in the C standard (§ 6.7.2.1) with regard to the instantiation of a struct that contains a FAM, the Marshal class simply does not accept them for interop with unmanaged code.

The way array members are usually marshalled is with the `MarshalAsAttribute`, like so:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=N)]
public byte[] msg_body;
```

where "N" represents the explicitly declared size of the array. Without this attribute, the `msg_body` member is treated as a pointer by the Marshal class. So, the size that `Marshal.SizeOf()` is returning is correct. Your generic `Serialize()` method won't work for structs that have a FAM.

You could modify it to copy over the contents of the FAM manually after the rest has been copied by the Marshal class, **but this seems like a rather awkward approach to binary serialization for a managed struct.**

```
// specify the name of the FAM and use reflection to get the value
// THIS ASSUMES that the FAM is always a byte[]

public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T s, string fam) where T : struct
{
  Type tt = typeof(T);

  // Reflection will get you the bytes in the FAM
  FieldInfo fi = tt.GetField(fam);
  byte[] famBytes = (byte[])fi.GetValue(s);

  // Get the field offset that corresponds to the unmanaged layout for
  // the FAM, according to the marshaller
  int offset = (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(tt, fam);

  var size = Marshal.SizeOf(tt) + famBytes.Length;
  BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("BLEGenericMsg Size: " + size + "\n");
  var array = new byte[size];
  var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
  Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, ptr, true);
  Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, size);
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

  // Now you're done with the marshalling, just copy over the contents of the
  // byte[] to your resulting array, starting at the correct offset
  Array.Copy(famBytes, 0, array, offset, famBytes.Length);

  return array;
}
```

Naturally, you will have to likewise modify the `Deserialize()` method to deal with structs that have a FAM.

**AGAIN, this seems like an awkward approach to this problem. You may want to really reconsider this approach.**

Comment: Thanks for the code help. I'm trying to follow what you posted. Am I suppose to pass msg_body into the serialize function as the string fam?  I'm up for any alternative ideas to accomplish this goal, but I havnt seen any.

Comment: Yes, pass `"msg_body"` as the name of the FAM member.

Comment: I think this is getting me close to where I need to be. There is now an additional 8 bytes on the end of the array, that I'm not sure why its there or where it came from.

Comment: No problem. It was a statement, not a question